# Mean value and variation of stationary independent incremental process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $X=\left \{ X(t);t\in T \right \}$ is a stochastic process and if for each $n$ and $t_{1}<t_{2}<...<t_{n}\in T$, we have $X(t_{2})-X(t_{1}),...,X(t_{n})-X(t_{n-1})$ are mutually independent we then call X be an independent incremental process, furthermore if for each $t,t+h,s,s+h\in T$, $X(t+h)-X(t)$ and $X(s+h)-X(s)$ share the same distribution then we call X a stationary independent incremental process, my book of stochastic process tells me that if $X=\left \{ X(t);t\in \overline{R}_{+} \right \}$ is a stationary independent incremental process, then $E(X(t))=Ct+E(X(0))$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X(t))=C_{1}t+\mathrm{Var}(X(0))$ here $C=E(X(1))-E(X(0))$ and $C_{1}=\mathrm{Var}(X(1)-X(0))$, but my book don't give any proof and I completely don't know how to prove it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need slightly stronger hypotheses for this. Some continuity/meaurability assumption is needed.
$EX_{t+s} =E(X_{t+s}-X_t)+EX_t=E(X_s-X_0)+EX_t$. So if we denote $EX_t$ by $f(t)$ then
then $f(t+s)=f(t)+f(s)-f(0)$. [$f(t)-f(0)$ satisfies the so-called Cauchy's Functional Equation]. It is known that any continuous (or measurable) function satisfying this equation has the form $f(t)=Ct+f(0)$

For the variance use a similar argument: note that $var [(X_{t+s}-X_t)+(X_t-X_0)]=var [X_{t+s}-X_t]+var (X_t-X_0)$ by independence.